# Infopath conditional formula in rules

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, form, infopath-data-connections

I need to connect an InfoPath view to a list in SharePoint which is already connected to another view of InfoPath form which submits the data to the list.
I need this second form to fetch particular fields and edit them in list.

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint list form customized with InfoPath can only write to the main data connection. In order to write to another list from the same form, you'd need code behind, which list forms don't support.

You can create several data connections to the same list to use for lookups, though.

And you can create different page views in the InfoPath form that do different things. Use the Form Load rules to determine which page view of the InfoPath form to show, based on values of list columns. For example, if you have a status column, let the Form load rule look at the status column value and if it is "in progress", then switch to Page view A, if it is "approved", switch to Page view B.